# Filtering RecyclerView's list with LiveData content using SearchView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I've created RecyclerView which contains simple list of words (String names of GroupVc objects). As list can be very long I want to make it filterable with SearchView in Toolbar.
Architecture of my application is based on Android Architecture Components, where all GroupVc objects exist in Room database and access to DataBase from UI is provided through ViewModel and Repository objects. I'm filing my RecyclerView with list of all GroupsVc wrapped in LiveData to keep it updated.
My problem is that I don't know how to make RecyclerView filterable. I tried to do it with implementing of Filterable Interface in adapter:

```
public class GroupsVcAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<GroupsViewHolder> implements Filterable{

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<GroupVc> mGroupsVc;
private List<GroupVc> filteredGroupsVc;
private OnItemClicked onClick;
public GroupsVcAdapter(Context context, OnItemClicked onClick) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.onClick = onClick;
}

public List<GroupVc> getmGroupsVc() {
    return mGroupsVc;
}

@Override
public GroupsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_of_groups, parent, false);
    return new GroupsViewHolder(itemView, onClick);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final GroupsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (mGroupsVc != null) {
        GroupVc current = mGroupsVc.get(position);
        holder.getNameView().setText(current.getNameGroup());
    } else {
        holder.getNameView().setText(R.string.nogroups);
    }
}

public void setGroupsVc(List<GroupVc> mGroupsVc) {
    this.mGroupsVc = mGroupsVc;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mGroupsVc != null)
        return mGroupsVc.size();
    else return 0;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mGroupsVc = (List<GroupVc>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            filteredGroupsVc = null;
            if (constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredGroupsVc = mGroupsVc;
            } else {
                filteredGroupsVc = getFilteredResults(constraint.toString().toLowerCase());
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredGroupsVc;
            return results;
        }
    };
}

protected List<GroupVc> getFilteredResults(String constraint) {
    List<GroupVc> results = new ArrayList<>();

    for (GroupVc item : mGroupsVc) {
        if (item.getNameGroup().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
            results.add(item);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
}
```

And then in Activity I've written a method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_words, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

The result was that my RecyclerView got filtered correctly but it wasn't restored after I closed SearchView. The only way to do it is to reload activity. **So I'm interested in How can I restore RecyclerView's list and can I use for filtering any LiveData's capacities?** Below I post the complete code of Activity, ViewModel and Repository:
```

**Activity**

```
public class GroupsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String DELETE_DIALOG = "Delete dialog";
private static final String EDIT_DIALOG = "Edit dialog";
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private GroupsVcAdapter adapter;
private GroupsViewModel mGroupsViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_groups);
    //Creating of toolbar with title Groups
    Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_groups);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    //Enable Up Button
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //RecyclerView containing the list of groups with sound icons
    mRecyclerView = initRecyclerView();
    //Using ViewModel to observe GroupVc data
    mGroupsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GroupsViewModel.class);
    mGroupsViewModel.getAllGroups().observe(this, new Observer<List<GroupVc>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<GroupVc> groupVcs) {
            adapter.setGroupsVc(groupVcs);
        }
    });
}

private RecyclerView initRecyclerView() {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.groups_recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    OnItemClicked listener = (v, position) -> {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.delete_group:
                Log.i(DELETE_DIALOG, "Delete button");
                break;
            case R.id.edit_group:
                Log.i(EDIT_DIALOG, "Edit button");
                break;
            case R.id.surface:
                Log.i(SURFACE, "Surface button");
                break;
        }
    };
    adapter = new GroupsVcAdapter(this, listener);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return recyclerView;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_words, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class GroupsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private LiveData<List<GroupVc>> mAllGroups;
private GroupRepository mRepository;

public GroupsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    mRepository = new GroupRepository(application);
    mAllGroups = mRepository.getAllGroupVc();
}

public LiveData<List<GroupVc>> getAllGroups() {
    return mAllGroups;
}
}
```

**Repository**

```
public class GroupRepository {
private LiveData<List<GroupVc>> mAllGroups;
private GroupVcDao mGroupVcDao;

public GroupRepository(Application application) {
    AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getInstance(application);
    mGroupVcDao = db.groupVcDao();
    mAllGroups = mGroupVcDao.getAllGroupVc();
}

public LiveData<List<GroupVc>> getAllGroupVc() {
    return mAllGroups;
}
}
```

Comment: Ok, It's something like query method which returns list of GroupVc based on constraint parameter?

Comment: @Query("SELECT * FROM groupvc WHERE name_group = :nameGroup")
    List<GroupVc> getFilteredGroupVc(String nameGroup);

Comment: The question's answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56394003/6884103

using switchMap and MutableLiveData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that your data is not restored correctly when you delete the filter is, because you overwrite your data list when you publish the filter result.

Here is the solution:

```
public GroupsVcAdapter(Context context, OnItemClicked onClick) {
  mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  this.onClick = onClick;

  // init the lists
  mGroupsVc = new ArrayList<>();
  filteredGroupsVc = new ArrayList<>();
}

public List<GroupVc> getFilteredGroupsVc() {
  return filteredGroupsVc;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
  return filteredGroupsVc != null ? filteredGroupsVc.size() : 0;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
  return new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
      filteredGroupsVc = (List<GroupVc>) results.values;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
      filteredGroupsVc.clear();
      if (constraint.length() == 0) {
        filteredGroupsVc.addAll(mGroupsVc);
      else {
        filteredGroupsVc = getFilteredResults(constraint.toString().toLowerCase());
      }

      FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
      results.values = filteredGroupsVc;
      results.count = filteredGroupsVc.size();
      return results;
    }
  };
}
```

If you set a new list of data to the adapter, you have to call `adapter.getFilter().filter(text);` or you save the last filter string inside your adapter and call your filter inside `setGroupsVc()`

Note:
You don't have any animations if you use `notifyDataSetChanged();`. If you want to have animations, use the other notify methods.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Also update `onBindViewHolder()` to get the data from your filtered list.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final GroupsViewHolder holder, int position) {
  if (filteredGroupsVc != null) {
    GroupVc current = filteredGroupsVc.get(position);
    holder.getNameView().setText(current.getNameGroup());
  } else {
    holder.getNameView().setText(R.string.nogroups);
  }
}
```

Now you always get the data from the filtered list. The initial state is that your lists is empty. That's what you saw in your `RecyclerView`. If you call `setGroupsVc()` you set a new list to the adapter. Remember you always get the data from the filtered list. So you have to update the filtered list (old data) with the new list which you set to the adapter (new data).

You have 2 options:

1. Call filter on the outside after you call `setGroupsVc()`:

Like

```
...
setGroupsVc(yourNewList);
adapter.getFilter().filter(searchview.getQuery());
...
```

2. Save the last filter in your adapter and call filter inside your `setGroupsVc()`:

Add new field `lastFilter` in your adapter

```
private String lastFilter = "";
```

Inside `performFiltering()` save the filter string

```
lastFilter = contraint.toString();
```

At least call filter in `setGroupsVc()`

```
public void setGroupsVc(List<GroupVc> mGroupsVc) {
  this.mGroupsVc = mGroupsVc;
  getFilter().filter(lastFilter);
  // notifyDataSetChanged(); -> not necessary anymore because we already call this inside our filter
}
```

Comment: I've changed my adapter according to your code https://gist.github.com/LAHomieJob/a2c43d49f82e6817e107f27ebc9e9fdc but it end up with complete empty recycler view until I not enter a text in searchView. And the results are not adequate. Could you explain me frase "If you set a new list of data to the adapter, you have to call adapter.getFilter().filter(text); or you save the last filter string inside your adapter and call your filter inside setGroupsVc()"

Comment: I've implemented both recommendations. Now it works much better - I retrieve correct results, but I still get empty screen within opening of activity. here is my updated gist https://gist.github.com/LAHomieJob/a2c43d49f82e6817e107f27ebc9e9fdc Also I added complete version of my GroupsActivity https://gist.github.com/LAHomieJob/aaa005eae27c6b2c25b1df1c27c3b89f Tomorrow I'm going to continue to work on this thread

Comment: I don't get your exact problem now... As you can see the adapter is initialized with an empty list. So there is no item inside your recyclerview until you call `adapter.setGroupsVc(yourNewList);` If you have a list of data, you can pass it to adapter's constructor and init your lists with this passed data instead of an empty list. Then your screen should not be empty.

Comment: But in my GroupsActivity class I've added this method's invocation adapter.setGroupsVc(yourNewList);. Look at lines from 70 until 75. I'm getting it from LiveData object

Comment: Well I don't understand your current problem. Can you explain it please? Then I can help you...

Comment: 1) I'm opening activity with RecyclerView and I'm watching at toolbar with searchView with no list at all - juxt empty screen. 2)To make item visible to me I need to type some characters and few items are appearing. The good news is that because of your last changes I receive fully correct filtered results and transitions from them into another groups are working in the way I want. But I stiil have a problem with empty starting screen and now I'm working on this issue.

Comment: I've finally got the solution! My mistake was that in row 83 instead of call method filteredGroupsVc.clear() I was writing filteredGroupsVc = null. So, your decision is fully correct